# Relationship: How to update a child field if the parent field is changed

Tags: c#, database, winforms, relationship

Hi guys before I ask this question I have looked at the question suggestions and there is none that could help me. I have a relationship between 2 tables (User and friends) How would I update the friends(Child) status field when the user(Parent) status field is changed?

Relationship:

[image: Relationship]

I've tried making a relationship so that if the user's status is changed it will automatically change the friends status:
[image: New Relationship]

But it doesn't update the friends status field when the user status is changed :/ Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Has the cascading update been propagated correctly to your RDBMS?

Comment: I don't think so. Do I need to make the status in the parent db a primary key?

Comment: No, I don't think making the user's status the PK is a good idea. What RBMS are you using, and how are you pushing your schema to it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ColumnChanging/ColumnChanged event of the Parent Table to catch the status changes. You could write you own business rules code in these event.

All Class generated by the TypedDataset Designer are partial (as Forms). Make a double click on the column and have a look at the code generated by Visual Studio.

```
Partial Public Class MyDataSet
    Partial Class MyDataTable

        Private Sub MyDataTable_ColumnChanging(sender As System.Object, e As System.Data.DataColumnChangeEventArgs) Handles Me.ColumnChanging
            If (e.Column.ColumnName = Me.MyColumn.ColumnName) Then
                'Add user code here - Get and update ChildRow

            End If

        End Sub

    End Class    
End Class
```

Or you could handle the event on the control editing the parents status value and update children status on the way.